# JavaScript Regular Expression to match digits too

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regex `/^[-.a-zA-Z\s]+$/`  to match any string contains only English letters, dashes and dots.

I would like to modify it to make it match any digit too.

so all these strings will be accepted:

```
first
first-floor
1st floor
floor No. 1
```

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Just add digits to your character class:

```
/^[-.a-zA-Z\d\s]+$/
```

Comment: dot and minus characters shouldn't be escaped?

Comment: No, they needn't be: the dot has no special meaning in a character class, and as the dash appears first, it does not denote an interval.

Answer (score 0):

you can also write:

```
 /^[-.a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/
```

Comment: `\d` and `0-9` are equivalent, at least in JS. Why the need to expand it out?